# How to draw an reactangle with some text using python

Tags: python-3.x, image, draw, paint

I want to draw in an image using python3. I have implemented same thing in android application using java. Looking for something to be done on the web application. You can see at the bottom of the image where I have used paint in android.

My image is :

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ru25.jpg)

I am not getting any library or a code snippet to do so in python. Any suggestions will be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pillow package provides the tools you need to add watermarks to your photos!

[How to Watermark Your Photos with Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/10/17/how-to-watermark-your-photos-with-python/)